# Http uncompressed content length protocol

Tags: http, compression, http-content-length

Does someone know wether some http version includes some uncompressed content length protocol? for example, in a cooperative environment where a client sends compressed payload to a server, such a protocol may be useful to optimize allocations on a server that decompress in memory.

Couldn't find something easily in the web